# Is there a way to run Airflow on multiple ports on same server simultaneously?

Tags: python, airflow

I would want to run 2 different airflow instances on same server. 1st on the default port 8080 and the other on some different port so that I have 2 airflow instances running simultaneously. As I understand that we can have only 1 airflow config file where we mention the port which is located in the airflow home folder that restricts to have multiple airflow instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely no problem. You can have different `AIRFLOW_HOME` settings for those two airflow. Airflow reads config file from the directory where `AIRFLOW_HOME` points to. Also logs/dags are written/read from subfolders of this directory (`logs` and `dags` respectively).

So simply run your second airflow with a different `AIRFLOW_HOME` and set different port in the other config and you will be good.